# Extra space when hiding nav bar on swipe in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to use the hideBarsOnSwipe so that when the user scrolls they can focus on the main content however, for some reason there's a space between the nav bar and the segmented control (custom one) when it starts hiding/showing[image]

Here's the code for this page

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                    VStack {     
                            .....           
                            ....
               
                           }
                       }
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
    
    
}
```

It's worth mentioning that there's another view that leads to this one. There's a master page with tab views where this view is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by removing the NavigationView. I read from another post that the Navigation View should be on the root view only.